# listing the category names in winforms like in web applications

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linkbutton

i have datagrid view with products the datagrid view will be loaded according to the categories selection on the left hand side of form that have in  datagrid view ...

I am in big trouble, as per client requirement is it possible to list the categories names like this in winform applications...(see the below image)

I know it is possible in web appliactions by using link buttons like that ..i dont know whether it is possible in windows type of apps ...

and i want to add the price range typesbelow that categories in same panel and i want to use these ones also as link buttons

**Example**: if i click one category name 1 the product list will be displayed in datagridview according to that category name...

that .....

**NOte** :the category names will be comes from database.. and this box will be placed in left side of windows form (like web applications ecommerce apps) [image]

would any one pls help on this......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever is possible in a web app is usually possible in winforms too...

For help with getting the display right, you can use ListView with grouping:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezh1batz.aspx

Comment: how we use link buttons ...suppose if i click on the one of the item in that i need to do something....like that

Comment: Use the ListView's SelectIndexChanged, then extract the data you need from the ListView's selected item. You can then change the DataSource of the DataGridView based on the new query. If this helps, mark me up... Thanks.